# yarn android not working with react native

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

i´m running my react native app with bare workflow, and when i try to execute it with **yarn android** i get this error:

```
Could not read script 'C:\Users\claud\OneDrive\├?rea de Trabalho\teste\node_modules\expo\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not exist.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "teste",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.9",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: you are running you app with expo not bare react-native all the script start with `expo`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of yarn's new policy, "PnP"!
There's a perfect workaround [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-yarn-3-with-react-native-and-how-to-migrate-c5f108108533)